# How can I test the limit of the number of threads with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Is it possible to automate the load tests in Jmeter and increase the number of threads until the first error is observed?

For example I start with testing 16 threads for every seconds and increase the number until i receive an error. But instead of doing this manually can I let this run automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Pre-defined Properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) section of JMeter's User Manual on Functions there is a `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` variable holding result of the last sampler execution.

So if you build your test plan as follows:

- Sampler which does test action
- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) checking whether previous sampler was successful

  - If not - relevant actions (stop test, send email, stop ramping up virtual users, etc.)

The value you need to put in "Condition" input of If Controller should look like

```
"${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}"=="false"
```

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) for more information on JMeter's If Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding threads in jmeter You may find those 2 links interesting:

- [What is the highest number of threads that is reasonable to simultaneously run in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-in)
- [JMeter max. thread limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528765/jmeter-max-thread-limit)

Regarding your methodology, why not use slow rampup and see the limit using what Dmitri T has provided ?