# What is the minimum and Maximum system configaration for using Jmeter appliacation?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to use above 5000 thread in Jmeter, SO what should be the system configuration. Now Am using 4GB RAM , 2.3 GHZ, Now it shows only 3000 threads results only in Summary Report.

2. In jmeter have any maximum number of limitation?

Comment: Do you get any errors in jmeter.log or in your test?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation except:

- Your machine CPU power
- Your memory and JVM size
- Your network interfaces

Answer depends on a lot of factor, You should read:

- [What is the highest number of threads that is reasonable to simultaneously run in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i/11922239#11922239) (The accepted answer is not correct anymore)
- [JMeter max. thread limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528765/jmeter-max-thread-limit)

So you will have to benchmark your machine with your plan and see to where you can go, then different options:

- 1 machine is ok, that's it
- You need more, switch to distributed testing or use a Cloud solution