# Jmeter - 22000 Concurrent threads - is it scalable?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Friends,

I went through differnt links in SO and internet regarding the max no of threads that can run in Jmeter and most of the answers are - it depends on hardware.

But my question is, provided my hardware configuration can handle 22,000 threads. Is jmeter capable of running a load test with 22,000 threads ?

What is the maximum number of threads anybody has used in the past using jmeter.

So far, in one of the SO link, few people have told they tested successfully till 150 threads. Anybody else tried more than this ?

**Update1**

As per this link, jmeter is used for almost 300 threads.
https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/08/17/how-many-threads-or-concurrent-users-can-i-run-in-parallel-with-apache-jmeter-from-my-machine/

**Update 2**

Many links in SO (including the one mentioned in comment) says that beyond 300, we should try other tools and also it is very much outdated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the highest number of threads that is reasonable to simultaneously run in Jmeter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you show in update is completely outdated and as you can see it's from loadfocus which proposes a concurrent approach so I would say it's not really neutral :-).

You can read this answer which is what you are looking for:

- [What is the highest number of threads that is reasonable to simultaneously run in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i/11922239#11922239)

It highly depends on your machine and your test plan and load test profile but we have experiences where we easily run 3000 threads on a 8vCPU / 8gb ram machine and there have been benchmarks showing a m2.xlarge Aws instance could sustain 
10000 threads.

So a 1000 threads is easily reachable.