# Maximum threads should use in a computer when testing load

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to load test for 5000 users. But they provide only 2 machines with the below mentioned configuration. How many threads I can use without any trouble. Both computers are in different subnets so I cannot use them in remote. Can I run the test at the same time in 2 machines independently and merge the result from log file. 
System configuration:
Ram 8 GB
CPU octa core 3.12 GHz
Swap memory 16 GB.
Linux cent 7 os.

Also can I save http response header.. Is it affect real time timing if I am not saving this response header.

Also I am using cache manager, cookie manager, pool size as 6 and constant timer.. Is there anything I missed to simulate real time result...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the highest number of threads that is reasonable to simultaneously run in Jmeter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer like "I can simulate this many users from my machine" as for every application for every single test scenario the numbers will be **different**.

- For instance if you need to test [IETF website](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2549) which basically returns small plain text pages - you can simulate i.e. 10 000 users on your hardware
- If you switch to i.e. picture gallery like [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/)- the users number will be less as response size will be larger, say 5 000
- If you need to test application assuming uploading and downloading large files, passing a lot of response parameters, intensive correlation and parametrization, etc. like online [content management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) the virtual users number may be as low as 1 000.

So the only way to determine how many virtual users you can produce for particularly your application under test is gradually increasing the load and monitoring resources on load generator side. Once CPU, RAM, Disk or Network IO usage exceeds 85-90% - this is the maximum your machine can produce for particularly that test scenario.

From "reality" perspective I would recommend using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to represent browser headers. Some applications produce different responses depending on the value of [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header, may provide compressed response triggered by [Accept-Encoding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) header, etc.